# spark sql - joining mssql dataframe with dataframe from different source

Tags: sql-server, scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

so I am creating 2 dataframes from 2 different sources. one source is mssql and the other could be anything like plain text. then what I want to do is join the 2 dataframes on a varchar column which if I was to do in SQL server, would be very expensive.

My question is would this operation be more performant in spark or does spark still have to do those joins/queries in SQL off that varchar column?

test code snippet:

```
sqlContext.read.format("jdbc").
  option("url", url).
  option("dbtable","FirstTable").
  load().createTempView("ft")

import sqlContext.implicits._

Seq(
  (1, "test1"),
  (2, "test2"),
  (3, "test3")
).toDF("id", "sfid").createTempView("test")


sqlContext.sql("select id,KeyId from ft inner join test on test.sfid = ft.KeyId").show()
```

is the table `"FirstTable"` loaded into memory first and then the join operation performed? or does spark somehow pass the expense of the join on the column KeyId to mssql?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> is the table "FirstTable" loaded into memory first and then the join operation performed?

Yes. Once the DataFrame has been created from the JDBC connect, all execution will take place in-memory in the Spark job.

Spark has a mechanism for pushing down processing to the source database, but it needs to be invoked explicitly in when invoking the jdbc reader.  You can do this by in-lining the query into the `dbtable` option.  Here's an example using MSSQL/PySpark:

```
jdbc_str = "jdbc:sqlserver://my.server:1433"
sqlserver_df = spark.read.format("jdbc").options(url=jdbc_str,
                                                 database="my_db",
                                                 user="my_user",
                                                 password="my_password",
                                                 dbtable="(select top 5 * from a_table) as t").load()
```